# Rspec 'trait not registered error when using Faker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, faker

I am trying to use `Faker` in `FactoryBot` in my Rails API tests.

The issue I am having that I keep getting this error:

```
KeyError:
       Trait not registered: "first_name"
```

So far as I can tell I have configured everything right, based on Faker'd docs at least. So far as I can tell I have two actual traits, `valid_user` and `invalid_user` that I set like so...

```
  let(:valid_attributes) { FactoryBot.attributes_for :api_v1_user, :valid_user }
  let(:invalid_attributes) { FactoryBot.attributes_for :api_v1_user, :invalid_user }
```

Which are linked to the `:api_v1_user` factory.

What have I missed or done wrong?

Full Error:

```
8) /api/v1/users PATCH /update with invalid parameters renders a JSON response with errors for the api/v1_user
     Failure/Error: let(:invalid_attributes) { FactoryBot.attributes_for(:api_v1_user, :invalid_user) }

     KeyError:
       Trait not registered: "first_name"
     # /home/etherk1ll/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/hash_with_indifferent_access.rb:191:in `fetch'
     # /home/etherk1ll/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/hash_with_indifferent_access.rb:191:in `fetch'
     # /home/etherk1ll/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/factory_bot-5.1.2/lib/factory_bot/registry.rb:23:in `find'
     # /home/etherk1ll/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/factory_bot-5.1.2/lib/factory_bot/decorator.rb:10:in `method_missing'
     # /home/etherk1ll/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/factory_bot-5.1.2/lib/factory_bot/internal.rb:49:in `trait_by_name'
     # /home/etherk1ll/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/factory_bot-5.1.2/lib/factory_bot/definition.rb:114:in `trait_by_name'
     # /home/etherk1ll/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/factory_bot-5.1.2/lib/factory_bot/definition.rb:106:in `block in base_traits'
     # /home/etherk1ll/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/factory_bot-5.1.2/lib/factory_bot/definition.rb:106:in `map'
     # /home/etherk1ll/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/factory_bot-5.1.2/lib/factory_bot/definition.rb:106:in `base_traits'
     # /home/etherk1ll/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/factory_bot-5.1.2/lib/factory_bot/definition.rb:51:in `block in compile'
     # /home/etherk1ll/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/factory_bot-5.1.2/lib/factory_bot/definition.rb:50:in `compile'
     # /home/etherk1ll/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/factory_bot-5.1.2/lib/factory_bot/definition.rb:130:in `aggregate_from_traits_and_self'
     # /home/etherk1ll/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/factory_bot-5.1.2/lib/factory_bot/definition.rb:34:in `to_create'
     # /home/etherk1ll/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/factory_bot-5.1.2/lib/factory_bot/trait.rb:17:in `to_create'
     # /home/etherk1ll/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/factory_bot-5.1.2/lib/factory_bot/definition.rb:135:in `map'
     # /home/etherk1ll/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/factory_bot-5.1.2/lib/factory_bot/definition.rb:135:in `aggregate_from_traits_and_self'
     # /home/etherk1ll/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/factory_bot-5.1.2/lib/factory_bot/definition.rb:34:in `to_create'
     # /home/etherk1ll/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/factory_bot-5.1.2/lib/factory_bot/definition_hierarchy.rb:16:in `build_from_definition'
     # /home/etherk1ll/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/factory_bot-5.1.2/lib/factory_bot/factory.rb:125:in `build_hierarchy'
     # /home/etherk1ll/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/factory_bot-5.1.2/lib/factory_bot/factory.rb:88:in `compile'
     # /home/etherk1ll/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/factory_bot-5.1.2/lib/factory_bot/factory.rb:32:in `run'
     # /home/etherk1ll/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/factory_bot-5.1.2/lib/factory_bot/factory_runner.rb:29:in `block in run'
     # /home/etherk1ll/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:182:in `instrument'
     # /home/etherk1ll/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/factory_bot-5.1.2/lib/factory_bot/factory_runner.rb:28:in `run'
     # /home/etherk1ll/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/factory_bot-5.1.2/lib/factory_bot/strategy_syntax_method_registrar.rb:20:in `block in define_singular_strategy_method'
     # ./spec/requests/api/v1/users_spec.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/requests/api/v1/users_spec.rb:92:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/rails_helper.rb:19:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # /home/etherk1ll/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/database_cleaner-1.8.4/lib/database_cleaner/generic/base.rb:16:in `cleaning'
     # /home/etherk1ll/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/database_cleaner-1.8.4/lib/database_cleaner/configuration.rb:87:in `block (2 levels) in cleaning'
     # /home/etherk1ll/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/database_cleaner-1.8.4/lib/database_cleaner/configuration.rb:88:in `cleaning'
     # ./spec/rails_helper.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ------------------
     # --- Caused by: ---
     # KeyError:
     #   key not found: "first_name"
     #   /home/etherk1ll/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/hash_with_indifferent_access.rb:191:in `fetch'
```

`spec/factories/api/v1/users.rb`

require 'faker'

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :api_v1_user, class: 'Api::V1::User' do
    trait :valid_user do
      first_name { Faker::Name.first_name }
      second_name { Faker::Name.second_name }
      username { Faker::Internet.username }
      email { Faker::Internet.safe_email }
      password { Faker::Internet.password(min_length: 8) }
    end


    trait :invalid_user do
      first_name nil
    end

  end
end
```

`rails_helper.rb`

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
require 'spec_helper'

ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../config/environment', __dir__)
# Prevent database truncation if the environment is production
abort("The Rails environment is running in production mode!") if Rails.env.production?

require 'rspec/rails'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

  DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  config.around(:each) do |example|
    DatabaseCleaner.cleaning do
       example.run
    end
  end

  config.before(:all) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:all) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end
```

`users_spec.rb`

Truncated

```
RSpec.describe "/api/v1/users", type: :request do

  let(:valid_attributes) { FactoryBot.attributes_for :api_v1_user, :valid_user }
  let(:invalid_attributes) { FactoryBot.attributes_for :api_v1_user, :invalid_user }

  let(:valid_headers) {
    {}
  }

  describe "PATCH /update" do
   context "with invalid parameters" do
      it "renders a JSON response with errors for the api/v1_user" do
        user = Api::V1::User.create! valid_attributes
        patch api_v1_user_url(user),
              params: { api_v1_user: invalid_attributes }, headers: valid_headers, as: :json
        expect(response).to have_http_status(:unprocessable_entity)
        expect(response.content_type).to eq("application/json")
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping the `nil` in brackets. FactoryBot [eliminated support for static attributes in version 5](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#static-attributes), so if you're using a newer version, that'll be your problem. Brackets are now required.

```rb
trait :invalid_user do
  first_name { nil }
end
```